# GDB shows No stack

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to run a test program to see how gdb (backtrace) shows the call stack. I have the following program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<assert.h>

void fun2()
{
        assert(0);
}
void fun1()
{
        fun2();
}
int main()
{
        fun1();
        return 0;
}
```

And i do the following:

```
g++ -g dump.cpp -o out 
./out
out: dump.cpp:16: void fun2(): Assertion `0' failed.
Abort (core dumped)
gdb out core.28149



(gdb) bt
No stack. //Why does it show no stack here
```

I was expecting it to show the call stack as :

```
fun2
fun1
main
```

Edit:
I edited the code and compiled as `g++ -g -O0 dump.cpp -o out`

But still i have **No Stack**

```
void fun2(int num)
{

        int h=23;
        if(h*num>100)
        {
                assert(0);
        }
        else
        {
                cout<<"Hello";
        }
}
void fun1(int num)
{
        {
                fun2(num);
        }
}
int main()
{
        int num;
        cin>>num;
        fun1(num);
        return 0;
}
```

Assembly code shows me this time the separate code for fun1,fun2(assert),main. But still I see No Stack in gdb

Comment: Try disabling optimization (add the flag `-O0`) and try again?

Comment: Are you sure `core.28149` was generated for `out` binary ? What is `file core.28149` output ?

Comment: `core.28149` is generated after runnig `out`. The output is pasted in the question itself below `./out`

Comment: If you run the program within gdb, are you able to get a backtrace? It's possible your core file is truncated because of ulimit.

Comment: ulimit -c is already set to unlimited

Comment: Can not reproduce this on linux with gcc 5.4 & gdb 7.11. I get trace as expected. Something is broken on your system.

Comment: Can you post whole gdb session when loading core dump ?

Comment: Well one thing i noticed is that gdb says `Reading symbols from /somepath here../tmp/out...done.
"/somepath here/core.30117" is not a core dump: File format not recognized`
This is weird because it _is_ the coredump because thats the only file which was generated after the program crashed.

Comment: What does the shell command `file /somepath here/core.30117` say the type is?

Comment: @Mark it says `core.28149: empty`

Answer (score 3):

> Reading symbols from /somepath here../tmp/out...done. "/somepath
>   here/core.30117" is not a core dump: File format not recognized

Your core dump is somehow corrupted. Actually it was not loaded by gdb so typing `bt` has no effect.

Try to examine it, these command should give you some info about core dump:

- `file core.28149`
- `strings core.28149`

Comment: The output of `file core.28149` is `core.28149: empty` .  And strings command doesnt have any output

Comment: This means that `core.28149` has no data, check your limits once again.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why gcc wouldn't optimise your program to

```
int main()
{
    assert(0);
}
```

To remove all doubt, check the generated assembly.

Comment: I'd expect `-O0` to prevent that, for debugging purposes.

Comment: Even if GCC could optimize the program to just main, GDB would *still* show something other than `no stack` for the core. `main` and `raise` would likely be on the stack for the reduced program.

Comment: -O0 still dindt help. It still shows No Stack. Assembly shows me different functions too. Still clueless why it doesnt show the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
$ clang++ -g -O0 -o dump dump.cpp

$ ./dump
100
Assertion failed: (0), function fun2, file dump.cpp, line 9.
Abort trap (core dumped)

$ gdb --core dump.core
. . .
Core was generated by `dump'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x000000080149f6ca in ?? ()
(gdb) file dump
Reading symbols from dump...done.
(gdb) set solib-search-path "/lib:<path>/llvm/lib"
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000080149f6ca in thr_kill () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x0000000801574149 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.7
#2  0x0000000801556011 in __assert () from /lib/libc.so.7
#3  0x000000000040130a in fun2 (num=100) at dump.cpp:10
#4  0x0000000000401343 in fun1 (num=100) at dump.cpp:20
#5  0x000000000040137e in main () at dump.cpp:27
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, gdb showed `No stack.` due to permission issues, when I tried attaching to process. To check if that's the case I used `sudo`:

```
sudo gdb -p <PID>
```